# Voyager: Quantum slipstream drive for Starfleet

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

On Voyagers return to the Alpha Quadrant they acquired some weapons and technology that would given Starfleet a big tactical advantage (Ablative armour, Transphasic torpedoes and Quantum Slipstream).

Now the armour and the torpedoes may have been confiscated by the temporal police, but not Quantum Slipstream, so my question is:

If Starfleet successfully integrated Quantum Slipstream tech on all of their ships, would they try and keep it a secret or would they share it with the Klingons?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this question dwells within the lands of SPECULATION.

NOTE: Confiscation of stolen technologies by the [Temporal Integrity Commission](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Temporal_Integrity_Commission) seems a moot point since the principle for knowing these technologies existed means some crafty engineer with time and a research team should be able to, in a few years, recreate prototypes of the technology, so removing them would only slow their development not stop it.

But for the sake of argument lets assume the [transphasic torpedoes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transphasic_torpedo) and [ablative armor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ablative_generator) from Janeway's 25th Century journey were confiscated. The [quantum slipstream drive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quantum_slipstream_drive), however, was acquired legitimately in the [Delta Quadrant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Delta_Quadrant).

Looking at the very sketchy notes for the Federation-Klingon Alliance I don't see any provisions for technology trade except as the governments decide to. I don't see anything indicating a mandatory sharing of said resources.

#### Treaty of Alliance (Federation-Klingon Alliance)

> - The Treaty of Alliance (also known as the Klingon Alliance) was the official agreement that established the alliance between the United Federation of Planets and the Klingon Empire.
> - Vulcan ambassador Sarek (TNG: "Sarek") was one of the key figures behind the negotiations that created the alliance, and his son, ambassador Spock, was the one who proposed the alliance. (VOY: "Alliances") The Treaty was regarded with controversy when first suggested, but later proved to be a cornerstone for peace in the Alpha Quadrant.
> - The Federation-Klingon alliance represented a fundamental shift in the balance of power in the Alpha and Beta Quadrants, as the two former enemies united. **According to the treaty's terms, each side could request the other's assistance in fighting against its enemies.**
> - This clause, in part, forced the Romulan Star Empire to the sidelines, unable to compete against the combined forces of the Federation and the Klingons. As a result, the Romulans devoted considerable resources towards trying to break up the alliance, albeit without success. (TNG: "Reunion", "The Mind's Eye", "Redemption", "Redemption II")
> - **The Treaty allowed the Federation to conduct health and safety inspections of Klingon vessels within Federation space. It also allowed for unrestricted travel by each side in the other's space.** (TNG: "Gambit, Part II")

#### Apocrypha

Several non-canon works address the quantum slipstream drive as a highly coveted technology, that several species were willing to try to steal or go to war over.

- [Star Trek: Destiny trilogy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Destiny)
- [A Single Destiny](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/A_Singular_Destiny)
- [Star Trek: Typhon Pact](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Typhon_Pact) - [Zero Sum Game](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Zero_Sum_Game)
- [Plagues of Night](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Night)

Comment: Would the alliance still have been in effect after the events of Deep Space Nine? Specifically, would it still have existed after the Federation and the Klingons had their little war?

Comment: Can ships travelling at Transwarp/Slipstream speeds be detected like normal warp speeds?

Comment: It would be safe to assume so since they are disrupting subspace like any other ship, just using a more advanced technology.

Comment: were the Borg ever detected during transwarp?

Comment: In 2373, when it became apparent that they were approaching Borg space, Harry Kim, operations officer on the USS Voyager, configured the ship's long-range sensors to scan for transwarp signatures, so as to provide an early warning system for the approach of Borg vessels. (VOY: "Scorpion"). See: [Transwarp Signature](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transwarp_signature)

Comment: So if you can pick up transwarp signatures then that negates the any tactical advantage transwarp has?

Comment: No. Transwarp is still faster and more efficient than regular warp drive, so detecting it and outrunning it are two different things.

Comment: @user16416: Just because you can detect an incoming ICBM on your radar screens doesn't necessarily mean you can do anything about it. :)